# best way to upgrade magento 2.1.15 to magento 2.4.4 Last version

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4

I have a huge client project running with ubuntu server LTS 20.04, so I need the best way to upgrade it from 2.1.15 to the last version 2.4.4 with the same data included, What is the best way?

```
1- Is it directly from 2.1.15 to the last version?
2- Upgrading 2.2 Then 2.3 Then 2.4?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.1.x can be directly upgraded to the latest version (2.4.4 at the moment). You need to consider the 3rd party extension compatibility and customised code, on latest Magento version and Php 8.1 as well.

It is recommended by Magento(Adobe) to use this upgrade compatibility tool. It makes the upgrade process a lot easier and we will get to know the pain points faster.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html

**EDIT:**
If you are running on Adobe Commerce cloud,You need to upgrade the ece-tools and also upgrade to a later Magento release.

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-upgrade-parent.html